# Evaluation of Integrals using Leibniz Formula

Tags: calculus

While evaluation of the integral $$\int_a^b{\frac{|x|}{x}}dx$$ we consider three cases:

Case 1: $0 \leq a < b$ then $f(x)=\frac{|x|}{x} = 1$, therefore $\int_a^bf(x)dx=b-a$

Case 2: $a < b \leq 0$, then $f(x)=-1$ and $\int_a^af(x)dx =a-b$ and

Case 3: $a < 0 < b$, then we divide the integral $\int_a^bf(x)dx$ into two Integrals $$\int_a^bf(x)dx=\int_a^0f(x)dx + \int_0^bf(x)dx = b-(-a)$$
But I want to know that for the integral $\int_a^bf(x)dx$ $f(x)$ must be continuous on the whole closed interval $[a, b]$ but then how can we evaluate $\int_a^0f(x)dx$ as $f(x)=\frac{|x|}{x}$ is not defined at $x=0$

Comment: Because $f(x)$ is bounded over the given interval,hence riemann integrable. (Intuitively if you think integrability as area of a curve then,why should discontinuity at a point affect it ?)

Answer (score 1):

Continuity is not  a requirement for integrability. Also if you change the value of a Riemann integrable function at one point it remains Riemann integrable and the volume of the integral does not change. Hence you can give any fixed value for $\frac {|x|} x$ when $x=0$ to make sense of the integral.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, in case you interest,  would be to use the fact that the derivative of $|x|$ is $\frac{x}{|x|} = \frac{|x|}{x}$ for $x\neq 0$. From here we got $$\int_a^b \frac{|x|}{x} dx = \int_a^0  \frac{x}{|x|} dx + \int_0^b  \frac{x}{|x|} dx= \left[|x|\right]_a^0 +  \left[|x|\right]_0^b= (0 -|a|)+ (|b| - 0) = |b| - |a|.$$